# jpackage without creating/bundling runtime

Tags: java, jpackage

Is there a way to tell `jpackage` (JDK15) to only package my application (jar-file) without creating and bundling a runtime?

I want that my application uses the jre/jdk which is already present on the host/customer system.
I know it is possible with `javapackager` from JDK8 but I can't find anything for JDK15.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't believe so, but you can check with the [user guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A) to double check. If this feature doesn't exist, and you can argue it would be sufficiently useful, then you can try the mailing list or submitting an issue.